# Convert Datetime in to Date in AngularJS Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to just get the date from the Datetime. I have below mytime variable which holds the date and time, here I just need the date in the yyyy-MM-dd format

```
    $scope.mytime = new Date();
```

I tried doing few things but it doesnt work

```
$scope.mytime.getdate();
```

which just returns `8` but I am looking for yyyy-MM-dd

I also did try

```
 $scope.newTime = $filter('date')(new Date(), "dd-MM-yyyy");
```

Got `$filter is not defined`

Comment: Inject `$filter` into your controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should inject the filters while using it in the controller as:

```
function appController($filter,$scope){

  $scope.newTime = $filter('date')(new Date(), "dd-MM-yyyy");

}

var app = angular.module('app',[]);
app.controller('appController',appController);

appController.$inject=['$filter','$scope'];
```